# Is there a case that Java String.hashCode() cache is invalidated?

Tags: java

In Java, when calling hashCode() on the one String instance multiple times in a single thread, is there a situation where the hash cache is not utilized and the hash is recalculated?

I'm profiling my application query with JFR's stackframe, it seems String.hash cache is not used weirdly and causes performance overhead.(OpenJDK 17)

It occurs only on production environment, and even I debugged Remote Process with jdwp,  I couldn't catch such case. (I set breakpoint at String.hashCode with condition to catch the weird case.)

Comment: If the calculated hash happens to be 0, then it will be recalculated each time. Alternatively the primary cause for such behaviour would be if you used different `String` instances with the same content (which obviously wouldn't share the `hash` field). Edit: I just checked [in Java 17](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk17/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/lang/String.java#L2328) and apparently they have added a `hashIsZero` field now to avoid this case).

Comment: I think the OP is alluding to a race condition, which is present and may result in a recalculation, but does not cause any correctness issues.  That said, I'm shocked about the hashIsZero...

Comment: @LouisWasserman: yes, I was surprised as well. There's a [length discussion on this topic](https://mail.openjdk.org/pipermail/core-libs-dev/2019-April/059441.html) which shows that the motivation was not (as I would have suspected) some kind of avoidance of a DoS with having to re-calculate the hash of a long attacker-controlled string over and over again, but rather with being able to store 0-hash strings in read-only memory areas. Another interesting detail is that according to one message the storage is "free" due to alignment gaps in `String` objects.

Comment: In your question, you mention "query". Is this a database query? When you say "one String instance", is this string instance in a DB? If so, you've got a separate Java String instance every time you get it from the query.

Comment: It means database query, but the application I'm profiling is the database(apache/druid).
The String instance should not have been copied...
I've also opened a issue.
https://github.com/apache/druid/issues/15242